Counter example: Variance of mean > variance of mixture
I am stuck with the following problem, any help is welcome:
Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two random variables. Let $p \in ]0;1[$. We denote $Y=pX_1+(1-p)X_2$ and $Z$ the mixture variable where $X_1$ has probability $p$ and $X_2$ has probability $1-p$.
It is clear that those variables have same expectation which is $p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2$ where $\mu_i$ is the expectation of $X_i$.
Now, regarding variances, in general, $Var(Y) \leq Var(Z)$. You can convince yourself studying the case where $X_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ is independent from $X_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$. In this case:
$$Var(Y)=p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2$$
and
$$Var(Z)=p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2+p(1-p)(\mu_1-\mu_2)^2$$
It is also clear for Dirac distributions.
My problem is that I can't find any proof to ensure that $Var(Y) \leq Var(Z)$ always. So my question is: do you think that it is possible to find a counter example where $Var(Y)>Var(Z)$? My guess is that it would be a case where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent.
Thanks for your help.

You can get equality if $X_1=X_2$.  I would be surprised if you can get $Var(Y)>Var(Z)$.

Thanks @Henry for your comment, I update the question to include the equality case.
